# Considering reapplying to a PhD program due to family emergency

Tags: phd, application

During last year's CS PhD application season, several elderly family members of mine were hospitalized due to COVID-19. I was greatly impacted by this event as they looked after me during my teenage years. As a result, I was not able to focus on school work for two months and ended up only submitting 3 applications. Fortunately, all of my family members recovered.

I end up getting admitted into one of the 3 programs I applied to, and it's a decent program. However, I'm considering reapplying next year because there are a few programs that I didn't apply to (I wanted to, but wasn't capable emotionally) but could likely offer a better fit in terms of research interest.

In particular, I will be reapplying to the program I got in. Would this be viewed negatively by the committee for that school? Or, would it be possible to defer my admission until next year? How should I communicate this to the admission committee at that school?

(Background: In general, the program allows for deferral.)

Any advice would help. Thanks.

Comment: why would you be reapplying to the program you got into, is there soem scolarship/fudning aspect here?

Comment: As I (perhaps) hinted in the prompt, there are other schools that could offer a better research fit (e.g., more potential advisors in area of interest). It would not be a terrible choice to attend the current program, but I'm simply asking for more choices as I'm planning on taking a gap year anyway in my home country after years abroad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any downside to applying anywhere you think would be a good fit. Universities certainly understand COVID disruptions.

I assume you turned down an invitation. You will need to decide whether to refer to that in a new application, but a few words should be enough in any written materials ("Family responsibility due to COVID..."). You might be asked in an interview and you can expand it there.

---

If you've been rejected by a place, though, it probably isn't worth the effort to reapply unless there has been a change in your CV and visible accomplishments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven’t turned down the offer yet. Can I defer the offer, apply to other schools, but make sure to accept/reject the deferral before next year’s decision deadline?

Comment: That is up to the school in question. You would need to ask them. But you might just phrase it as a delay in acceptance for family/medical reasons and see if they are happy with that.

Comment: Do you mean it’s better to keep it he excuse “general” as opposed to going into full detail (ie, I’m reapplying because I only applied for 3 schools last time due to family/medical emergency)?

Comment: I wouldn't talk to one school about applications elsewhere. That doesn't seem productive.

Comment: I see. I’m just concerned that the school could ask: “why don’t you just defer as opposed to delaying acceptance?” It would be hard for me to provide a reasonable answer without mentioning other schools.